# prevent DOMParser parseFromString to unescape html

Tags: javascript, html, xml

Is there a way to prevent DOMParser.parseFromString to unescape HTML ?

ex:

`(new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString("<test>&lt;p&gt;</test>", "text/xml")` 
return :
`<test><p></test>`

It would like it to return
`<test>&lt;p&gt;</test>`

Comment: are you sure it's returning `<` and `>`, and not just RENDERING the `&lt;` and `&gt;` as `<>`?

Comment: @MarcB, do you know how to get the raw string `<test>&lt;p&gt;</test>`? :)